# how to parse json , every time changing id on instagram

Tags: c#, json

```
{"reels":{"6592252783":{"id":"6592252783","latest_reel_media":1668086478,"expiring_at":1668172878,"seen"....
```

How can we do 6592252783 is changing every time.

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class _16278726
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int latest_reel_media { get; set; }
    public int expiring_at { get; set; }
    public int seen { get; set; }
    public bool can_reply { get; set; }
    public bool can_gif_quick_reply { get; set; }
    public bool can_reshare { get; set; }
    public bool can_react_with_avatar { get; set; }
    public string reel_type { get; set; }
    public object ad_expiry_timestamp_in_millis { get; set; }
    public object is_cta_sticker_available { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int prefetch_count { get; set; }
    public int media_count { get; set; }
    public List<string> media_ids { get; set; }
}
```

ı use online json to c# converter .How should it be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing Dynamic JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965936/parsing-dynamic-json-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Newtonsoft.Json you can do it in one line

```
Reel reel = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["reels"]).Properties().First().Value.ToObject<Reel>();
```

your class

```
public class Reel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int latest_reel_media { get; set; }
    public int expiring_at { get; set; }

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JsonDocument` to parse the mentioned json. And then use the `EnumerateObject` method to dynamically enumerate the object's properties. And then parse the object into mentioned class like below :

```
var json = @"{""reels"":{""6592252783"":{""id"":""6592252783"",""latest_reel_media"":1668086478,""expiring_at"":1668172878,""seen"":1668172878}}}";
var reels = JsonDocument.Parse(json).RootElement.GetProperty("reels");      
var enumerated = reels.EnumerateObject().First(); // first property is the property with the key 6592252783
var obj = enumerated.Value;     
var deSerialized = obj.Deserialize<Root>();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g93Mx3)